# Combobox + Arraylist + SQL

Tags: java, sql, query, combobox, arraylist

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte problema em questão:

Fiz uma array list para listar dados em uma combo box, mas ela só lista os dados da primeira tabela, no caso: "catdesc", que é a descrição de uma categoria de carro, se ele é Esportivo, etc.
Mas na mesma tabela, tem uma coluna chamada catvalordiaria, ou seja, é o valor da diária desta categoria de carro.

No combobox aparece apenas a descrição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero mostrar, ao lado dessa descrição, o valor da diária, ex: Esportivo - R$ 39,90;
Não sei se o problema é porque o valor é double, ou sla, preciso da ajuda de vocês. Aqui está meu código do "CategoriaDao" e logo abaixo o Servicos.java, onde faz a listagem das categorias no Combo Box.

```
package model.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import model.bean.Categoria;
import model.connection.ConnectionFactory;


public class CategoriaDao {

    Connection con=null;
    String sql;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement pstm;

    ArrayList<Categoria> listacat=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Categoria> listarCategorias(){

        try{           

         con=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();         
         sql= "SELECT catcodigo,catdesc,catvalordiaria FROM categoria ORDER BY catdesc";    
         pstm=con.prepareStatement(sql);            
         rs=pstm.executeQuery(sql);

         while(rs.next()){

         Categoria cat = new Categoria();

         cat.setCatCodigo(rs.getInt(1));
         cat.setCatDescricao(rs.getString(2));
         cat.setCatValorDiaria(rs.getDouble(3));
         listacat.add(cat);

         }

        }catch(Exception erro){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro PSTM "+erro.getMessage());


        }

        return listacat;

            }

}
```

```
    public void preencherComboCategoria(JComboBox comboCategoria){

        CategoriaDao cat = new CategoriaDao();

        List<Categoria> listagem2 = cat.listarCategorias();

        for(Categoria c:listagem2){


            comboCategoria.addItem(c);


    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível abstrair os dados necessários para um novo objeto de transição, assim você não usaria a entidade `Categoria` direto numa camada de visualização, o que é considerado uma má prática. Dessa forma você poderia ter um atributo que é a concatenação de `catdesc` com `catvalordiaria`.

Por exemplo:

```
public class CategoriaViewModel {
    private int codigo;
    private String descricao;

    public String getCodigo() { return this.codigo; }
    public void setCodigo(String codigo) { this.codigo = codigo; }
    public String getDescricao() { return this.descricao; }
    public void setDescricao(String desc) { this.descricao = desc; } 
}
```

Esse seria seu objeto de transição, o que você irá exibir na view. Para obtermos ele precisamos preenche-lo de acordo com os dados que vem da camada DAO. Pra isso podemos usar um conversor, onde você irá passar objetos do tipo `Categoria` e ele converterá para objetos do tipo `CategoriaViewModel`.

```
public class CategoriaConversor() {

    /**
     * Em geral, os métodos de conversão não recebem tipos List,
     * e sim o tipo em si, no caso Categoria. 
     * Porém pra simplificar o exemplo será com list.
     **/
    public List<CategoriaViewModel> convert(List<Categoria> categorias) {
        List<CategoriaViewModel> viewModels = new ArrayList<CategoriaViewModel>();

        for (Categoria cat : categorias) { 
            CategoriaViewModel viewModel = new CategoriaViewModel();
            viewModel.setCodigo(cat.getCatCodigo());

            //Aqui é onde a descrição é concatenada e montada com desc + valordiaria
            viewModel.setDescricao(String.format("%s - %s", cat.getCatCodigo(),
                                   cat.getCatValorDiaria()));
            viewModels.add(viewModel);
        }

        return viewModels;
    }
}
```

E no seu método de preenchimento do ComboBox você converte para o tipo `CategoriaViewModel`:

```
CategoriaConverter converter = new CategoriaConverter();
List<CategoriaViewModel> categorias = converter.convert(cat.listarCategorias());

for(CategoriaViewModel cat : categorias) {
    comboCategoria.add(cat);
}
```

Desse jeito você evita de usar o objeto de entidade direto na camada de visualização, mantendo-o inalterado e fiel ao que você trouxe do banco de dados caso você use a mesma instância pra outros fins.